# Proving Question (Complex Numbers, De Moivre's)

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Prove that

$$(1+\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)^n + (1+\cos \theta - i \sin \theta)^n=2^{n+1}\cos^n\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{n\theta}{2}$$

I want to avoid using the $e^{i\theta}$ form since I haven't learnt it yet.

I have tried changing 1 into $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta=(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)(\cos\theta-i\sin\theta)$ and factorising each bracket, but it just ends up being a chain of the same expression.

EDIT:

I have done a solution that uses double angle formulae for trig:
$1+\cos2x=2\sin^2x$
$\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$

Now,
$(1+\cos x + i\sin x)^n
=(2\cos^2 x+i(2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}))^n$

$=[2\cos\frac{x}{2} (\cos\frac{x}{2} + i\sin\frac{x}{2})]^n$

And using De Moivre's, and multiplying the power through,

$=2^n \cos^n \frac{x}{2} (\cos \frac{nx}{2} + i \sin \frac{nx}{2})$

A similar process is used for the other bracket and then I use simple algebra to get the RHS.

Thanks for your suggestions though!

Comment: Have you considered induction?

Comment: Better change $1=\cos(0)+i\sin(0)$. Then use the Prosthaphaeretic trigonometric identities to add $\cos(0)+\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(0)+\sin(\theta)$.